# Can this be done using Sylow theorems?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct primes.Suppose that $H$ is a proper subset of the integers and $H $is a group under addition that contains exactly three elements of the set {$p,p+q,pq,p^q,q^p$}.Determine which of the following are the three elements in $H$.

> **a.**  $pq,p^q,q^p$
>
> **b.** $p,p+q,q^p$
>
> **c.** $p,p^q,q^p$
>
> **d.** $p,pq,p^q$

Comment: A group must contain an identity element, but I don't see how any of these four elements can be $0.$

Comment: @awllower:Here, H contains only three elements  of the given  set,not H is a group with three elements.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. Maybe the term *intersection* can be helpful in formulating here?

Comment: @AndréNicolas:thanks a lot, i only wanted to know  this.

Comment: If you prefer closing the two duplicate in the reverse direction, vote accordingly and comment here (ping me also, if you don't mind:-). I picked the other version over this, because it is not written as a multiple choice question (something that many users dislike).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ have the form $n\mathbb{Z}$ for some non-negative integer $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $H$ contains two relatively prime integers, then it contains all the integers.

Comment: I already  did this using this notion,i want to try it using Sylow's theorems. I want to know whether it can be attempted using sylow's theorem.

Comment: @PRADEEPSINGH: The Sylow theorems are about finite groups, and are of interest only for non-Abelian groups. I cannot think of a way to apply them in our setting.

Comment: @PRADEEPSINGH: Maybe one could look at the quotient group $\mathbb{Z}/H$. But to say anything about the quotient group brings us first to carmichael561's solution, which is group-theoretically better than mine, I automatically went into number-theoretic mode!